# few vim autoinserts for ruby needed

Tags: ruby, vim

I want to try the following things in vim insert mode:

- to have closing bracket/parenthesis inserted (after the cursor) every time I type the opening one
- to have `#{}` inserted whenever I type `#` inside `""` (optionally, inside `%()` too)

I know it is possible, but my competence in this part of vim does not even reach the self-starter level.

Answer (score 2):

[This script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849) will do the first one (auto inserting the closing bracket and placing the cursor between the brackets.)

Answer (score 1):

[lh-brackets](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets) helps define brackets related mappings. It also provides a few functions aimed at defining context-sensitive mappings and abbreviations (see `Map4TheseContext`).

If in ruby %() is associated to a syntax highlighting, `Map4TheseContext` will also solve your last request. If not, you'll have to play with `searchpair()` to detect the current context. Let me know if you have troubles to come up with a working solution.